# Was Lando trying to warn off our heroes?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

It's funny how after having seen it a hundred times, all these years later, I keep finding new things in the Star Wars Trilogy. It never occurred to me until the other day why the Millenium Falcon received such a chilly welcome to Cloud City - because Lando was hoping that they would turn back, perhaps?

Or am I overthinking this? I read the novelization around the time that the movie came out, but I've since reclaimed those sectors...does anyone have any secondary information on this?

Comment: Yes, I've thought this too, but maybe instead it was frustration showing after just being surprised/interviewed by Vader.

Comment: It could just have been a tell that Han didn't pick up on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He was delaying so Vader could get everything in order in Cloud City.  Lando says, "They arrived *just* before you did."  (emphasis mine).  Vader wanted them in the air as long as possible.

Answer (score 8):

Not that I'm aware of from EU.

The reason he was chilly towards Han was because a wee bit earlier (2.5BBY) Han won Millenium Falcon from him in Sabbac. (Source: Han Solo trilogy, "*Rebel Dawn*")

More specifically:

- They were in a high stakes Cloud City Sabacc Tournament. Yes, the same Cloud City featured in ESB.
- Lando was a professional gambler, Solo was a scoundrel smuggler who just lost his ship and a bunch of money.
- They ended up in the final round
- Lando ran out of money so he added a marker for "any ship on my lot" - IIRC, he owned a used ship outfit?
- When Han won with Pure Sabacc, he told Lando he was taking Millenium Falcon - Lando's personal ship and his pride and joy. Lando tried to argue that he didn't mean Falcon, but Solo said "Well, it's in your lot isn't it?" (since Lando took a cruise ship to the tournament, instead of low-lifing it and flying the Falcon).

So THAT's how Solo ended up owning Falcon, and how Lando ended up hating his guts for a while.

Comment: From what I recall, Lando had hired Han to teach him how to pilot a ship, which was how Han encountered the MF.

Comment: Is Sabbac any relation to Pazaak?

Comment: @GabeWillard - according to Wookiepedia Sabacc article, it was a successor game to Pazaak. Both are blackjack like. and do sound similar

Comment: That's how Solo ended up owning the Falcon, sure, but when I read Rebel Dawn the more significant portion (in relation to Lando being chilly towards Solo) is that Solo recruited Lando (and other smugglers) for the Rebel raid on Ylesia promising a share of the spoils. The Rebels double-crossed them all, Han included, and Lando blamed Solo for this, suggesting, IIRC, that as Han was sleeping with the Rebel leader Bria Tharen he *must* have known in advance that that was the plan.

Comment: @PhilPursglove - Great point, I blanked out on that one. Add as an answer

Answer (score 3):

No he was ordered by Vader to admit him. He probably was chilly so Han and the others wouldn't be suspicous.